# How to implement gatsby-remark-images-grid in markdown using Gatsby.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, gatsby

I'm making a blog in Gatsby.js using markdown and I want to use CSS grid in my blogposts to display a nice grid of images.

So I know Gatsby has got fantastic plugins to solve almost every problem.

I found out about gatsby-remark-images-grid which is supposed to solve my problem, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I did install it correctly (I think: `npm install gatsby-remark-images-grid --save`), put it in my gatsby-config.js, which looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Kids and Coconuts',
    siteUrl: 'https://kidsandcoconuts.com',
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: 'gatsby-starter-default',
        short_name: 'starter',
        start_url: '/',
        background_color: '#663399',
        theme_color: '#663399',
        display: 'minimal-ui',
        icon: 'src/images/gatsby-icon.png', // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-catch-links`,
    'gatsby-plugin-offline',
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          `gatsby-remark-prismjs`,
          
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-images-grid",
            options: {
             
            },
        },

        ]
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/content`,
        name: "pages",
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

and I tried to put a image grid in one of my blogpost:

````
```
![](../time.jpg)
![](../time.jpg)
```
````

Does somebody see what am I forgetting or doing wrong?

Comment: In `gatsby-remark-images-grid`'s readme, it states that you'd need to specified amount of column following the `\`\`\`` backtick (i.e `\`\`\`grid|2|`). Did you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Define the path in the markdown file. If markdown files are in `src/pages/index.md` and in `src/images/image.jpg` you would put this in the MD file.

```
   images:
  - /images/image1.jpg
  - /images/image2.jpg
  - /images/image3.jpg
```